# Tiling two images together without spaces in java

Tags: java

i have two jpg images, and i am supposed to tile two images side by side in such a way that, the two images looks like they are joined.

Can anyone suggest me how to overcome this difficulty????

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.imageio.ImageReadParam;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.awt.Color;

import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64;

public class GetImage0 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
try {
File f = new File("1.jpg");
 BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(f);
height = image.getHeight();
int width = image.getWidth();
System.out.println("Height of image 1 : "+ height);
System.out.println("Width of image 1 : "+ width);
File f1 = new File("2.jpg");
BufferedImage image1 = ImageIO.read(f1);
int h = image1.getHeight();
int w = image1.getWidth();
System.out.println("Height of image 2 : "+ h);
System.out.println("Width of image 2 : "+ w);

    String filename = System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator;
    BufferedImage img1 = ImageIO.read(new File("1.jpg"));       
        BufferedImage img2=ImageIO.read(new File("2.jpg"));
        BufferedImage joinedImg = joinBufferedImage(img1,img2);
    boolean success = ImageIO.write(joinedImg, "jpg", new File("joined.jpg"));
        System.out.println("saved success? "+success);

} catch (IOException ioe) {
ioe.printStackTrace();
}


File file = new File("C:/Documents and Settings/LFFR1/Desktop/image_0.jpg");

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    //create FileInputStream which obtains input bytes from a file in a file system
    //FileInputStream is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as image data. For         //reading streams of characters, consider using FileReader.

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    try {
        for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
            //Writes to this byte array output stream
            bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); 
            System.out.println("read " + readNum + " bytes,");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GetImage0.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
}

public static BufferedImage joinBufferedImage(BufferedImage img1,BufferedImage img2) {

    //do some calculate first
    int offset  = 5;
    int wid = img1.getWidth()+img2.getWidth()+offset;
    int height = Math.max(img1.getHeight(),img2.getHeight())+offset;
    //create a new buffer and draw two image into the new image
    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(wid,height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = newImage.createGraphics();
    Color oldColor = g2.getColor();
    //fill background
    g2.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, wid, height);
    //draw image
    g2.setColor(oldColor);
    g2.drawImage(img1, null, 0, 0);
    g2.drawImage(img2, null, img1.getWidth()+offset, 0);
    g2.dispose();
    return newImage;
}

}
```

This is the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "joined"? something along the lines that the're blending into one another?

Comment: 1. Too broad. 2. Unclear. 3. Lacks sufficient information. 4. 0 research effort.

Comment: It seems there is a lot of irrelevant code in your posting, and also a compilation error (height is not declared). Also, please fix the indentation to make it easier for us to understand and reenact your code. BTW, he's getting `javax.imageio.IIOException: Invalid argument to native writeImage`.

Comment: @LaurIvan Actually, i need to tile the images such that they seem to be a single image... like kinda attachment of two images

Comment: @AVGSankeerth You really should upload or link to a "before/after" image describing what you want, or create an ascii art if you can't upload images.

Comment: @AVGSankeerth I'm still unclear. Do you mean something like [blending](http://cs.brown.edu/courses/csci1950-g/results/proj2/edwallac/) around edges? or just simple scaling images until they have the same height/width?

Comment: yeah...thats what im looking for @LaurIvan. But as stated, there is a gap coming in between the joined images.... they look like they are placed besides each other, instead of getting joined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to summarise the above:

First, the code `g2.drawImage(img2, null, img1.getWidth()+offset, 0);` practically pastes the second image at a distance.

```
       v--- offset
######...======
#img1#...=img2=
######...======
```

You may want to have it like `g2.drawImage(img2, null, img1.getWidth(), 0);`. Then the images will have no gap.

```
######======
#img1#=img2=
######======
```

Then, you may want to crop or scale images so they have the same height. Have a look at [cropping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116448/cropping-an-mage-in-java)/[scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967731/java-scale-image-best-practice) algorithms.

For the blending of images, there are lots of algorithms out there. You can for example apply alpha channel fading to transparent at corners and overlap the images. You can do the same alpha and stretch the images' sides that are joining and *then* overlap. You can apply something similar to what phones do when you take a panorama image. You need to decide exactly how the joint side needs to look and find/build the algorithm to do exactly that.

Comment: Thank you. If you think my reply answers your question, please tick it :)